# Android fast searching

Tags: android

am using fts3 tabele for searching my problem is, I have invoking search in textWatch listener of the EditText, when I type 'a' it start search for 'a', then I type 'b' it search for 'ab' only after the result of 'a' comes, how can I solve this issue, that means when I type 'b', it stop searching of 'a' and start searching of 'ab' . Currently my search slow because of this issue, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you can try to optimize your query.

1. Check out sqlite [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#like_opt) for how to optimize LIKE statements
2. Make sure you have indexes on the rows you'll perform filtering
3. If still not working fast enough try to do some precomputation or build some data structure to restrict the search set

Comment: my sql query contain lot of like statement and it make the search slow,so i use the fts3 table ,which provide fast search

Answer (score 0):

Is the column you are searching in indexed? Adding an index will make a huge difference.

Otherwise/in addition, you should [enable profiling](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) the code and look at it with `traceview` to better understand where the time is really spent.